# Proving that an infinite series equal a finite series

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-verification, residue-calculus

Suppose we have a function $f(z)$, which has $m$ isolated singularities, which are non-integers (say, $z_1$, $z_2$,...,$z_m$). Define $H(z):=\frac{\pi f(z)}{\sin(\pi z)}$. Assume that there exists a set of curves $\Gamma_n$ such that each of the singularities of $H(z)$ will be eventually contained in $\Gamma_n$ for $n$ large enough. Also assume that there is a finite constant $C$ such that $\forall n$ and $\forall z\in \Gamma_n$, $\left|\frac{1}{\sin(\pi z)}\right|<C$. Show that for $f$ satisfying *certain conditions* $\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^k f(k)=-\sum\limits_{l=1}^m Res_{z=z_j} \{H(z)\}$. Determine what conditions $f$ must satisfy.

> My proof:

We know that $$\int_{\Gamma_n}H(z)dz=2\pi i \underbrace{\sum\limits_{l=1}^m Res_{z=z_j} \{H(z)\}}_\text{all residues of $f$} +2\pi i \underbrace{\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^k f(k)}_\text{all residues of $H$ at integers $k$}$$

It appears that we only need to prove that $$\int_{\Gamma_n}H(z)dz=0\text{$\space\space\space\space$   (1)}$$

Now, $$\int_{\Gamma_n}H(z)dz< C\pi\int_{\Gamma_n}\left|f(z)\right|dz$$

If we assume that $f$ is analytic in small neighbourhoods of $z_i$ ($1\le i \le m$), this will imply that $z_i$ are removable singularities of $f$. But this implies that $f$ is analytic in the entire small neighbourhoods, and so it is analytic everywhere where $H$ is analytic. Thus if we take $\Gamma_n$ to be defined on rectangles $\pm(n+\frac{1}{2})\pm i(n+\frac{1}{2})$, then (1) will be true.

Please let me know if my proof is correct. I'm somewhat in a doubt because I don't quite understand why $H(z)$ would be analytic on $\Gamma_n$, because $\Gamma_n$ seems to include integers on the real line anyway.

Comment: you mean $H(z)$ not $G(z)$

Comment: and for $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\Gamma_n} H(z) dz = 0$ it is enough that as $n \to \infty$, $|H(z)| \to 0$ fast enough on $\Gamma_n$  (try with $H(z) = \frac{1}{(z+i) (z+2 i)\sin(\pi z)}$ and $\Gamma_n $ the rectangle $\pm i n \pm \infty$  (for crossing the real line, you pass in the middle of two zeros of $\sin(\pi z)$)

Comment: @user1952009 sorry, corrected.

Comment: " and Γn the rectangle ±in±∞ (for crossing the real line, you pass in the  middle of two zeros of sin(πz)"

- Sorry, didn't quite understand this.

Comment: let $H(z) = \frac{1}{(z+i)(z+2i)\sin(\pi z)} $ you see that $\lim_{m \to \infty} \int_{-n+ i m/2}^{n+ i m/2} H(z) dz = \lim_{m \to \infty} \int_{-n- i m/2}^{n- i m/2} H(z) dz = 0$ so $\int_{-in -\infty}^{-in +\infty}+\int_{in +\infty}^{in -\infty} H(z) dz  = 2i\pi( Res(H(z),-i)+Res( H(z),-2i)+\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty Res(H(z), k)) $

Comment: finally you need to show that $\int_{-in -\infty}^{-in +\infty}+\int_{in +\infty}^{in -\infty} H(z) dz \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ which is obvious since $\sin(\pi z)$ increases exponentially as $Re(z) \to \pm \infty$

Comment: I forgot to say $m$ is odd (so that in $\int_{-n+im/2}^{n+im/2} H(z) dz$ we pass in the middle of two poles)

Comment: I think I'm lost.

Comment: then let $n,m \to \infty$ all in one by looking at (for $n$ odd) $\int_{n+in}^{-n+in}+\int_{-n+in}^{-n-in}+\int_{-n-in}^{n-in}+\int_{n-in}^{n+in}H(z) dz$ and its limit as $n \to \infty$